# Compare two files with Aptana

Tags: diff, compare, aptana, aptana3

I remember that before I updated my Aptana installation it had the ability to compare two selected files via right-click -> compare. Now it doesn't seem to have this feature enabled...

I wonder if there is a way to achive the same in version 3, build: 3.2.0.201206251729.

Thanks in advance and have a good one!!! :)

PD: When I right click any file the option to compare doesn't appear. Plus the menu "Team" desappeared

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to change to the proyect explorer view, then you'll see the compare option after right clicking the selected files :)